# AES GCM encrypt with web subtlecrypto and decrypt with flutter cryptography

Tags: flutter, dart, encryption, subtlecrypto

I'm trying to encrypt something in a webextension with [SubtleCrypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto) and decrypt it in flutter with [cryptography](https://pub.dev/packages/cryptography).  I want to use a password to encrypt a message, send it to a app and decrypt it with the same password. For this I use AES GCM with pbkdf2

I was able to find an encryption snippet on the Mozilla documentation page. However, I struggle decrypting it in flutter.

I'm also having problems with terminology. SubtleCrypto uses iv, salt and tags while flutter cryptography uses nonce and mac.

Javascript code:

```
test(){
  // const salt = window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(16));
  // const iv = window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(12));
  const salt = new Uint8Array([0, 72, 16, 170, 232, 145, 179, 47, 241, 92, 75, 146, 25, 0, 193, 176]);
  const iv = new Uint8Array([198, 0, 92, 253, 0, 245, 140, 79, 236, 215, 255, 0]);

  console.log('salt: ', salt);
  console.log('iv: ', iv);
  console.log('salt: ', btoa(String.fromCharCode(...salt)));
  console.log('iv: ', btoa(String.fromCharCode(...iv)));

  this.encrypt('value', salt, iv).then(x => console.log('got encrypted: ', x));
}

getKeyMaterial(): Promise<CryptoKey> {
  const password = 'key';
  const enc = new TextEncoder();
  return window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
    'raw',
    enc.encode(password),
    'PBKDF2',
    false,
    ['deriveBits', 'deriveKey']
  );
}

async encrypt(plaintext: string, salt: Uint8Array, iv: Uint8Array): Promise<string> {
  const keyMaterial = await this.getKeyMaterial();
  const key = await window.crypto.subtle.deriveKey(
    {
      name: 'PBKDF2',
      salt,
      iterations: 100000,
      hash: 'SHA-256'
    },
    keyMaterial,
    { name: 'AES-GCM', length: 256},
    true,
    [ 'encrypt', 'decrypt' ]
  );

  const encoder = new TextEncoder();
  const tes = await window.crypto.subtle.encrypt(
    {
      name: 'AES-GCM',
      iv
    },
    key,
    encoder.encode(plaintext)
  );

  return btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(tes)));
}
```

flutter dart code:

```
void decrypt(){
final algorithm = AesGcm.with256bits();

final encrypted = base64Decode('1MdEsqwqh4bUTlfpIk12SeziA9Pw');

final secretBox = SecretBox.fromConcatenation(encrypted, nonceLength: 12, macLength: 0);

// // Encrypt
final data = await algorithm.decrypt(
  secretBox,
  secretKey: await getKey(),
);


String res = utf8.decode(data);
}

Future<SecretKey> getKey() async{
  final pbkdf2 = Pbkdf2(
    macAlgorithm: Hmac.sha256(),
    iterations: 100000,
    bits: 128,
  );

  // Password we want to hash
  final secretKey = SecretKey(utf8.encode('key'));

  // A random salt 
  final salt = [0, 72, 16, 170, 232, 145, 179, 47, 241, 92, 75, 146, 25, 0, 193, 176];

  // Calculate a hash that can be stored in the database
  final newSecretKey = await pbkdf2.deriveKey(
    secretKey: secretKey,
    nonce: salt,
  );

  return Future<SecretKey>.value(newSecretKey);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *"However, I struggle decrypting it in flutter."* How do you struggle with it? What are the symptoms?

Comment: If aiming for compatibility with `crypto.subtle` it might be worth taking a look at: https://pub.dev/packages/webcrypto, it specifically aims at compatibility with `crypto.subtle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following issues exist in the Dart code:

- The WebCryptoAPI code concatenates the GCM tag with the ciphertext in the order *ciphertext | tag*. In the Dart code, both parts have to be separated accordingly.
  Also, in the Dart code, the nonce/IV is not taken into account. A possible fix of `decrypt()` is:

```kt
   //final secretBox = SecretBox.fromConcatenation(encrypted, nonceLength: 12, macLength: 0);
   Uint8List ciphertext  = encrypted.sublist(0, encrypted.length - 16);
   Uint8List mac = encrypted.sublist(encrypted.length - 16);
   Uint8List iv = base64Decode('xgBc/QD1jE/s1/8A'); // should als be concatenated, e.g. iv | ciphertext | tag
   SecretBox secretBox = new SecretBox(ciphertext, nonce: iv, mac: new Mac(mac));
```

- In addition, the WebCryptoAPI code uses AES-256, so in the Dart code in `getKey()`, 256 bits must be applied as the key size in the PBKDF2 call accordingly.
- Also, since `decrypt()` contains asynchronous method calls, it must be marked with the `async` keyword.

With these changes, `decrypt()` works on my machine and returns `value` for the data from the WebCryptoAPI code:

```js
function test(){
    // const salt = window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(16));
    // const iv = window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(12));
    const salt = new Uint8Array([0, 72, 16, 170, 232, 145, 179, 47, 241, 92, 75, 146, 25, 0, 193, 176]);
    const iv = new Uint8Array([198, 0, 92, 253, 0, 245, 140, 79, 236, 215, 255, 0]);

    console.log('salt: ', salt);
    console.log('iv:   ', iv);
    console.log('salt:         ', btoa(String.fromCharCode(...salt)));
    console.log('iv:           ', btoa(String.fromCharCode(...iv)));

    encrypt('value', salt, iv).then(x => console.log('got encrypted:', x));
}


function getKeyMaterial() {
    const password = 'key';
    const enc = new TextEncoder();
    return window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
        'raw',
        enc.encode(password),
        'PBKDF2',
        false,
        ['deriveBits', 'deriveKey']
    );
}


async function encrypt(plaintext, salt, iv) {
    const keyMaterial = await getKeyMaterial();
    const key = await window.crypto.subtle.deriveKey(
        {
            name: 'PBKDF2',
            salt,
            iterations: 100000,
            hash: 'SHA-256'
        },
        keyMaterial,
        { name: 'AES-GCM', length: 256},
        true,
        [ 'encrypt', 'decrypt' ]
    );

    const encoder = new TextEncoder();
    const tes = await window.crypto.subtle.encrypt(
        {
            name: 'AES-GCM',
            iv
        },
        key,
        encoder.encode(plaintext)
    );

    return btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(tes)));
}

test();
```

```
salt:          AEgQquiRsy/xXEuSGQDBsA== 
iv:            xgBc/QD1jE/s1/8A 
got encrypted: 1MdEsqwqh4bUTlfpIk12SeziA9Pw
```

Note that a static nonce/IV and salt are generally insecure (for testing purposes it's fine, of course). Usually, they are randomly generated for each encryption/key derivation. Since salt and nonce/IV are not secret, they are typically concatenated with the ciphertext and tag, e.g. *salt | nonce | ciphertext | tag*, and separated on the recipient side.

Actually `SecretBox` provides the method `fromConcatenation()` which is supposed to separate a concatenation of nonce, ciphertext and tag. However, this implementation returns (at least in earlier versions) a corrupted ciphertext, which is probably a bug.

---

Regarding the terms nonce/IV, salt and MAC/tag in the context of GCM and PBKDF2:

The GCM mode uses a 12 bytes nonce, which is called an IV in WebCryptoAPI (and sometimes in other libraries), s. [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/71219). PBKDF2 applies a salt in the key derivation, which is called a nonce in Dart.

The naming *nonce* is appropriate in that, an IV (in combination with the same key) and a salt (in combination with the same password) may only be used once. The former is essential for the GCM security in particular, s. [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/68525).

MAC and tag are synonyms for the GCM authentication tag.

Comment: That all makes a lot of sense. If it wasn't for that bug, this should work as well?: `final encrypted = base64Decode('xgBc/QD1jE/s1/8A1MdEsqwqh4bUTlfpIk12SeziA9Pw');
    final secretBox = SecretBox.fromConcatenation(encrypted, nonceLength: 12, macLength: 16);`

Comment: @RobinDijkhof - Correct, without the bug this would work. In the current version Cryptography 2.0.1 the bug is still present (tested). This can even be seen in the source code given in the [description](https://pub.dev/documentation/cryptography/latest/cryptography/SecretBox/fromConcatenation.html): In `final cipherText = List<int>.unmodifiable(...` a wrong offset is used.